# Meshlab vertex attribute 'vsel' is missing

Tags: meshlab

I need to use meshlab vertex attribute **vsel** to define a **per vertex normal fuction**. But meshlab is saying *unexpected token vsel*.  [image: meshlab vsel]

I am sure that this attribute exists in some Meshlab version, as I found this top google image in which **vsel** attribute is mentioned  along with the **vtu**, **vtv**, **vi** etc. However in my Meshlab I don't have this attribute function as one can see below in the image.

[image: meshlab vsel]

My only guess is that I need to upgrade or downgrade my meshlab version but I couldn't find any detail of Meshlab version which has this **vsel** feature.  I am using Meshlab v1.3.2_64bit

Answer (score 0):

The vsel variable is in meshlab since version 2016.12. You can get that version from the official meshlab webpage.